# Pluralizer model names in entity framework core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

We are in the process of migrating an existing application to .NET core. To do so, we also need to move towards code first models.

I scaffolded our database to models. This works fine. The models are generated in singular form:

```
public partial class Order
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string AssemblyUnitName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Serial { get; set; }
}
```

The reference in the db context is also in singular form:

```
public partial class KappContext : DbContext
{
        public KappContext()
        {
        }

        public KappContext(DbContextOptions<KappContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        ...
        public virtual DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
        ...
}
```

To reduce the impact of refactoring too much code, we want our models in the database context to be in the pluralized form, e.g.:

```
public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```

When I do this, by just renaming and I execute some code like:

```
var orders = await _context.Orders
                .OrderBy(ot => ot.OrderNumber)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync();
```

this throws an exception:

```
SqlException: Invalid object name 'Orders'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__164_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)
System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask<TAntecedentResult, TResult>.InnerInvoke()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task+<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(object obj)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref Task currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, bool result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<TResult>>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Kapp.Controllers.OrderController.Get() in OrderController.cs
+
            var orders = await _context.Orders
```

I already tried to use the bricelam pluralizer. This is not supported in .NET core 3 anymore.

I also tried to implement a design service, implementing the IPluralizer interface, but this is also not supported in .NET core 3 anymore.

How can i achieve to have pluralized property namings for my models in my database context?

Comment: What do you mean by "IPluralizer is also not supported in .net core 3 anymore"? The interface is still present in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design version 3.x, hence definitely is supported. Just make sure to reference it properly as explained in the 3.0 breaking changes - [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is now a DevelopmentDependency package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#dip).

Comment: I Ivan, i tried this, and I also followed the recommendations from that link, but still, it couldn't find or reference the IPluralizer interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default behaviour of EF Core uses `DbSet<T> ProperName` as a table name when you query.

```
public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```

You can override it

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .ToTable("Order");
}
```

Comment: Hi, this solved my issue, but i run into another one. When i update inverse properties from 
public virtual ICollection<ActionListItem> ActionListItem { get; set; } to public virtual ICollection<ActionListItem> ActionListItems { get; set; } (pluralized), i get error messages: InvalidOperationException: The InversePropertyAttribute on property 'Action' on type 'ActionListItem' is not valid. The property 'ActionListItem' is not a valid navigation property on the related type 'Action'. Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation property. any idea on that?